# D: Passing a constructor to std.algorithm.map

Tags: constructor, d

I have a class called `Node` whose constructor takes a single `int` argument, and would like to use it as part of a call to `map` to create a whole array of Nodes from an array of ints. I know that `map` can be given any function, but does this include constructors, and if so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like this

`auto nodes_array = ints_array.map!(a => Node(a)).array;`

Comment: Thank for that. Is there a way to have whatever ``map`` returns be an appropriate array, rather than a ``MapResult!(some_lambda,some_array_type)``? In this case, I would like ``nodes_array`` to be a ``Node[]``, rather than the type ``map`` returns for me in this case.

Comment: You can notice the .array call at the end. It does exactly what you want - takes an input range (MapResult in that case) and makes an array out of it. You should import std.array to use this function.